# Does CrudRepository.save return null for spring data 1.13.18.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-commons

I understand that for the current version(`2.x.x`) of `spring-data-commons` it is [guaranteed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) that the return value of `CrudRepository.save()` will never be null. However, what about the older versions, specifically [1.13.18.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.13.18.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-)?

If the older version does guarantee return of non-null values then it renders the following piece of code useless, right?

```
        Entity savedEntity = someRepository.save(entity);
        if (savedEntity == null) {
            // throw some checked exception stating that the save failed..
        }
```

And if the older version doesn't guarantee return of a non-null value, then what scenario would lead to the return of a null value?

**Update**: 
Since my question is pertaining to the implementation of `CrudRepository`, it is important to point out that I am using `1.11.18.RELEASE` of `spring-data-jpa`. I want to know about the behaviour of [save](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/ca247106fd292edcbb34a32c4e7fed93ca65c1f8/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L505) function for this version.

Comment: It doesn't look like either enforce non null returns. I can't see anything in the code to suggest it isn't entirely up to the implementation to decide this.

Comment: @123 can you elaborate? Are you trying to say that even the current/latest version doesn't enforce non-null returns? If that is the case then isn't the documentation misleading?

Answer (score 1):

same issue here.
Even though it should never return null, in my project I get a null value (silent failure) when I update an existing entity.
If I create a new entity it works. I tried also implementing the Persistable interface, but still the same issue.
I am using Spring Data + R2DBC + Java 15.

Answer (score 0):

According to [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/1.11.18.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java), it will always return a value or throw an exception

**Update** the implementation is for `1.11.18.RELEASE`. From GitHub repository

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        this.em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return this.em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to include details of the implementation I am using. The link you shared, I believe, is for the latest version `2.x.x`.